# cakephp sending encrypted data to library from Controller

Tags: php, cakephp

While working with the cakephp, I found an issue mentioned below.

1. Fetched the encrypted field info from DB (encrypted using Security::rijndael)
2. Passed this whole data as an array format to the custom Library(Own created lib).

When i echoed the data in lib as well in controller I amazed to see the result. The value (encrypted one) are showing blank in the lib. Is I missed anything in codding? I searched on google but didn't get the satisfactory answer, Please help me out. Your help will really be appreciated.

Here is result i am getting in controller  and Library respectively

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => s�i�(�RTf���cBЉF� | �r�n@ô�
        )
)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] =>
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your character encoding; a place I worked at ran into a similar issue and it was due to our db trying to encode characters it did not support. `UTF-8 generic` is a, well, generic encoding type.

Comment: Yes I made the required changes (enabled the character encoding) in database.php. Now I can see the value but that too are different than what has been saved in DB. Now it surprises me more than when i have not enabled the UTF-8 encoding....

Comment: Try passing the data between two controllers in cake (no your lib). See what happens. Also can you provide the method call and declaration of the method in the lib for us. TY

Comment: Passing data from controllers working fine :). The issues raised when data is being passed to Lib.

Here is Lib function that being called from controller
LibClassName::changeEntitiesStructure($array_of_encrypted_data);

Lib function structure:
function changeEntitiesStructure($arr)
{
    $val = $entity[0]['value'];

    if($decryption_req)
    {
 $new = new Cfss;
 $val = $new->decryptValue($val);
    }}

Comment: `(Please ignore the above Lib function mentioned) 
Lib function structure:


function changeEntitiesStructure($arr)
{
    $val = $entity[0]['value'];  // 

    if($decryption_req)
    {
 $LibObj = new LibClassName; // TO access self class function
 $val = $LibObj->decryptValue($val); // Here 
    }
}



public function decryptValue($val)
{
    $key = KEY;
    $decrypted = Security::rijndael($val, $key, 'decrypt');
    return $decrypted;
}`

Comment: changeEntitiesStructure($arr) $arr is not used with the function. this on purpose?

Security::rijndael($val, $key, 'decrypt'); are you sure it should not be $key, $value, 'options' ?

Outside of those two, is there a 3rd party library you could try for the en/decrypting?

Comment: sorry to forget to mention the purpose of $arr:
changeEntitiesStructure($arr)
{
foreach($arr as $entity)
{
$val = $entity[0]['value']
}
}

Yes this Security::rijndae($value, $key, $type) is a correct format.
I have another way of implementing this functionality but i am looking for the reason behind this issue.  btw thanks for your help.
I will definitely update here as soon as i will get the right solution/reason.

Comment: Ok, defiantly let me know when you find out why this is not working for you.